# Delete method in plain Ruby is not working

Tags: ruby

Please see below.

The delete method is not working and I do not know why.

I am trying to delete a customer without using rails and just plain ruby.
please can you help.

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
from /Users/mustafaalomer/code/MustafaAlomer711/fullstack-challenges/02-OOP/05-Food-Delivery-Day-One/01-Food-Delivery/app/repositories/customer_repository.rb:28:in `delete'
from /Users/mustafaalomer/code/MustafaAlomer711/fullstack-challenges/02-OOP/05-Food-Delivery-Day-One/01-Food-Delivery/app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:33:in `destroy'
from /Users/mustafaalomer/code/MustafaAlomer711/fullstack-challenges/02-OOP/05-Food-Delivery-Day-One/01-Food-Delivery/router.rb:36:in `route_action'
from /Users/mustafaalomer/code/MustafaAlomer711/fullstack-challenges/02-OOP/05-Food-Delivery-Day-One/01-Food-Delivery/router.rb:13:in `run'
from app.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

```rb
require_relative "../views/customers_view"
require_relative "../models/customer"


class CustomersController
  def initialize(customer_repository)
    @customer_repository = customer_repository
    @customers_view = CustomersView.new
  end

  def add
    # ask user for a name
    name = @customers_view.ask_user_for(:name)
    # ask user for a address
    address = @customers_view.ask_user_for(:address)
    # make a new instance of a customer
    customer = Customer.new(name: name, address: address)
    # add the customer to the repository
    @customer_repository.create(customer)
    list
  end

  def list
    customers = @customer_repository.all
    @customers_view.display_list(customers)
  end

  def destroy
    # ask user for the id to delete
    list
    id = @customers_view.ask_user_to_delete(:id)
    # customer = @customer_repository.find(id)
    # @customer_repository.delete(customer)
  end
end
```

```
require 'csv'
require_relative '../models/customer'

class CustomerRepository
  def initialize(csv_file)
    @csv_file = csv_file
    @customers = []
    @next_id = 1
    load_csv if File.exist?(csv_file)
  end

  def all
    @customers
  end

  def create(customer)
    customer.id = @next_id
    @customers << customer
    @next_id += 1
    save_csv
  end

  def find(id)
    @customers.find { |customer| customer.id == id}
  end

  def delete(id)
    @customers.delete { |customer| customer.id == id}
  end

  private


  def save_csv
    CSV.open(@csv_file, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << %w[id name address]
      @customers.each do |customer|
        csv << [customer.id, customer.name, customer.address]
      end
    end
  end

  def load_csv
    CSV.foreach(@csv_file, headers: :first_row, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      row[:id] = row[:id].to_i
      @customers << Customer.new(row)
    end
    @next_id = @customers.last.id + 1 unless @customers.empty?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`delete`](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/array#method-i-delete) always takes an argument.

[`delete_if`](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/array#method-i-delete_if) can be given a block and seems to be what you're looking for.